# Webpage: Use part of the URL as input

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, web

The page http://www.dayscore.net generates a user-specific key which is appended to the URL and then could be used as a simple authentification-method.

Sadly I wasn't able to find how this could work and if it is possible to build something like this on my webspace. I read about .htaccess redirecting but it was mostly about simply redirecting a page from A to B.

What I want to do is the following:

- The user calls the URL `http://www.mywebsite.com/foobar`
- It redirects internally to `http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php`
- In `index.php` it is possible to find out that the user called `foobar` and do something according to this input
- The redirection is just internal, the user still sees `http://www.mywebsite.com/foobar` in his address bar

Is this comparable to the mechanic DayScore implemented?
How would it be possible to implement such a webpage (.htaccess?) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this inside one .htaccess file in the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /([^/]+)/?$  [NC]
RewriteRule .*   index.php?key=%1  [L]
```

Maps silently

`http://www.mywebsite.com/val`

To

`http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?key=val`

Where `key` is any fixed key name and `val` is a variable value in the incoming URL.

`/val` must be the last string in the incoming URL for the rules to work.

The `key` is what the script gets with `$_GET['key']` in index.php.

Comment: This does work. Unfortunately this does not map silently (at least in Chrome 24). The silent part is just an optional thing which would be cool, so thanks a lot so far!

Comment: @MOnsDaR  Modified my answer. Sorry. I mentioned it is a silent mapping but by mistake left the flag for permanent redirection. For silent mapping the flag at the right is `[L]`, for permanent redirection are `[R=301,L]` and for temporal redirection are `[R=302,L]`.